# Using the global styles.css file

Tags: css, angular

I'm going through a tutorial right now for Angular 4 and trying to apply CSS styles to my component with the styles.css file found in the src folder. In the tutorial, the teacher just wrote normal CSS. When I tried to do that, I kept getting errors. Finally I figured out how to get it to work by doing this:

```css
body, h1;

body {
  background-color: purple;
  }
  
h1 {
  color: yellow;
  }
```

Why did I need to put `body, h1;` at the top of the page like variables when he didn't have to do that in the tutorial?

Comment: What were the errors you've got?

Comment: None of the CSS code was showing up and I got red squiggle lines under all of my css code there, even though the lint program in VSCode recognized that it was a CSS file and I wrote valid CSS.

Comment: Did you have some errors in the console? These were the one I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be using sass and your teacher using standard css. Glad you figured it out anyway.

Comment: I'm not though as far as I know. I have it installed on my computer but I haven't imported it to this project or anything.